# Intuitively explanation of covariance in terms of association

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I recently read this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555855/why-is-a-regression-coefficient-covariance-variance, and I really liked @Marjolein Fokkema's intuitive explanation of Pearson correlation is. In particular, it was

> The correlation coefficient tells us: If $x$ increases by $\sqrt{var(x)}$, how many $\sqrt{var(y)}$s will outcome $y$ increase? Thus, with a correlation coefficient of 1, an increase of 1 SD in $x$ is associated with an increase of 1 SD in $y$.

Now, I am wondering **is there a similar explanation of covariance?** Let's say that $Cov(X, Y) = C$, does that mean that an increase of $\sqrt{var(X)}$ in $X$ is associated with an increase of $C \cdot \sqrt{var(Y)}$ in $Y$ (in raw amount)?

Comment: It really should say average change. As to your question, if $X$ changes by one SD, the product of the two changes is the covariance.

Comment: So you mean "an increase of $\sqrt{var(X)}$ in $X$ is associated with an increase of $\frac{C}{\sqrt{var(X)}}$ in $Y$ (in raw amount), on average" ?

Comment: More generally, "an increase of $a$ in $X$ is associated with an increase of $\frac{C}{a}$ in Y, on average" ? Is this true?
I wonder if we can prove this.

Comment: No, of course not; the changes are directly, not inversely, proportional. But when $X$ changes by _exactly_ one SD, the product is the covariance.